# BrowserRouter causes React App to not load (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

If I remove the `<Router>` and `</Router>` tags below, the App loads as usual. But adding these in results in a blank page (the app doesn't load)

Strangely enough, the problem also occurs if I turn these tags into comments. E.g. `//<Router>` and `//</Router>`.

I installed the most up-to-date (v6) of react-router-dom. The problem also occurs if I use HashRouter instead.

From my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

From my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

function App(){
  return(
    <h1>Hi</h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shared in the snippet. Are you saying the entire React application isn't running/mounting? Or specifically that there's an issue rendering the `App` component? Can you include all relevant code you are working with and clarify more clearly the issue? What is `App` component rendering? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Drew - the app can run via yarn start, but none of the components render (I get a blank page). I edited the post to include my app.js file. Hope that helps.

Comment: There ***must*** be something else going on as this is a trivially minimal amount of `react-router-dom` code. I am unable to reproduce the issue as you describe in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/browserrouter-causes-react-app-to-not-load-react-router-dom-020cti). Are there any errors in the console? How are you running your application?

Comment: Can you share your package.json file and the exact steps/commands you are using to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Package.json shared above - it's the standard one that comes with create-react-app. 

Commands: just "yarn start" or "npm start". I've tried loading the page on Safari, Chrome, Firefox on my macOS device. I've also used a windows device on the local network to access it. No luck so far... Could it be a problem with the IDE? I'm on the latest version of npm and yarn as well. Honestly at a loss

Could it be a problem with the newest versions of create-react-app and react-router-dom not mixing?

Comment: `react-router-dom` isn't listed as a dependency. Run `npm i -s react-router-dom` to install it and update your package.json file, then run `npm start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `react-router-dom` hasn't been added to your project as a dependency and likely isn't installed locally for when you are building the app.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react": "^18.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

Run `npm install –save react-router-dom` (*or `npm i -S react-router-dom`*) to install and add `react-router-dom` to your project's dependencies.

From here you should be able to add the router code to your app and run it using `npm start`.